# jqgrid change primary key name from id for inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a field called date in the jqgrid and its colModel is like this :

```
{name:'date',index:'date', width:40, sorttype:"date",key:true,label:"date"},
```

So this is the primary key which is passed for inline editing. But the issue is, the value is

posted with key name as id. How can I change it to date ? My POST is like :

```
revenue1            0
id                  2013-12-12
revenue2            1
oper                edit
```

I would like to change it to :

```
revenue1            0
date                2013-12-12
revenue2            1
oper                edit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) of jqGrid:

```js
prmNames: { id: "date" }
```